# Is there any way where I could embed my stack overflow profile on my website?

Tags: discussion, design, api

I wanted to embed few contents of stack overflow like reputation, badges on my personal website? Is there any api to do so? What are the various options and how could I implement it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, You can embed your stackoverflow profile onto your website using your user [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flair).

see here https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Simply copy and paste the HTML snippet(you will get one in the above link)  wherever you want to show off your Stack Overflow flair

Comment: Hi, this is giving an image, is it possible to fetch the details as text?